# Loop filter colname using R

Tags: r, loops, filter

I am trying to write this in a better way using R:

````
  filter(V1 != 1) %>% 
  filter(V2 != 2) %>% 
  filter(V3 != 3) %>% 
  filter(V4 != 4) %>% 
  filter(V5 != 5) %>% 
  filter(V6 != 6) %>% 
  filter(V7 != 7) %>% 
  filter(V8 != 8) %>% 
  filter(V9 != 9)```
````

Answer (score 0):

With `BaseR` you can loop like,

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    
    df <- df[df[,paste0("V",i)]!=i,]

}
```

**Fake Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(round(runif(100,1,10)),10))
colnames(df) <- paste0("V",1:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with `dplyr` in one line. Suppose `cols` is a vector of column names and `cutoffs` is a named vector of corresponding cutoffs for each column in `cols`.

```
cols <- paste0('V', 1:9)
cutoffs <- setNames(1:9, cols)
```

Then, we can filter data frame `df` with `dplyr` by:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(across(all_of(cols), ~ .x != cutoffs[cur_column()]))
```

Test:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:9, 100*9, T), nrow = 100))
x <- df %>% filter(across(all_of(cols), ~ .x != cutoffs[cur_column()]))

colSums(mapply(`==`, x, cutoffs))
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 
#  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

- use `filter(across....` style of syntax
- `~` starts an invisible function
- `.x` represents the column value
- `cur_column()` represents the column name.  Using `str_remove` removes `V` from colname and `as.numeric` converts it to numeric.

So this may also do

```
#some sample data creation
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(matrix(round(runif(100,1,10)),10))
colnames(df) <- paste0("V",1:10)

df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   5  1  2  1  3  6  1  2  6   3
2   8  9 10  9  9  7  6  7  5   7
3   7  6  5 10  5  2  2  2 10   9
4   4  6  3  9 10  6  5  9  7   6
5   7  8  6  6  2  4  9  2  4   3
6   7  3  9  3  8  3  2  5  3   9
7   7  6  9  9  9  5  2  5 10   7
8   3  9  9  3  1  4  7  4  8   8
9   8 10 10  9  1  9  3  7  5   8
10 10  6  8  5  8  8  1 10  5   7
```

syntax

```
df %>% filter(across(everything(), ~ .x != as.numeric(str_remove(cur_column(), "V")) ))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  8  9 10  9  9  7  6  7  5   7
2  7  8  6  6  2  4  9  2  4   3
3  7  3  9  3  8  3  2  5  3   9
4  7  6  9  9  9  5  2  5 10   7
5  8 10 10  9  1  9  3  7  5   8
6 10  6  8  5  8  8  1 10  5   7
```